# How to copy file content automatically to another file when saved?

Tags: file, launchd

I’d like to automatically copy the contents of a file `file.a` to `file.a.b` whenever `file.a` is saved by any program. The following is what I tried so far with a LaunchAgent, but it doesn’t work yet.

**1. Create script to copy the file contents**

```
#!/bin/bash
say "Script is running"
cd /path/to/folder
cat file.a > file.a.b
```

make it active with `chmod -x copy.sh`. This script works when I run it manually via `sh script.sh` or with a global hotkey from Alfred.

**2. Create a LaunchAgent**
I build it with Lingo but saved it manually since Lingo won’t save the file …

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>de.tweh.SaveCSStoCSSPHP</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/script/copy.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/path/to/folder/file.a</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**3. Save LaunchAgent**
I saved the agent as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/de.tweh.DoCopy`

**4. Restart**
Restart my Mac to activate the LaunchAgent.

What am I doing worg?

**Edit**
The Console gives this (useless?) error message:

```
16.06.13 00:44:04,005 com.apple.launchd.peruser.502[153]:
(de.tweh.DoCopy[326]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Console application to see what the logs say?

Comment: @ayaz: Not yet, but it isn’t helpful (for me) … see my edit …

Comment: @ayaz: Thanks that led me to the solution :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error: I used `chmod -x` instead of `chmod +x`. Now it works fine :-)